# Count tabs per line in text file with utils

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, utilities, wc

I have a tab-tabulated file.
I would like to check if every line has the same number of tabs.

For first step, I'd like to print the number of tabs for each individual line.

I've tried `grep -o '\t' infile | wc -l`, but my implementation of `grep` says `grep: invalid option -- o`. Is there an other way?

---

Nice to have: if possible, due personal preference, I'd prefer to do this with util (grep, cat, etc.) tools, preferably *not* `awk` or bash scripting.

Comment: The `-o` option for `grep` is not POSIX. What OS are you on?

Comment: @jordanm I'm on ubuntu, however I'm helping out a friend who is using windows with the utils from msysgit that his company has preinstalled.

Comment: Just so you know, your `grep` command wouldn't have worked anyway, you should specify `\t` as `$'\t'` but anyway, `wc -l` would give you the total number for the whole file, not for each line. I can't find a way of getting info per line without a minimum of awk/bash/perl etc.

Comment: Best way to help your friend is probably not "Here's a nickel, kid. Get yourself a better computer" but if they're going to insist on crippling their toolkit it's the only accurate one. `awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} NR==1{f=NF} f!=NF { print "tab mismatch at line "NR; exit 1; }' `

Comment: @terdon I think it worked for me, however I edited to use `'\t'` and tested it on my box.

Comment: @naxa it didn't :). Try counting manually, `'\t'` will count the number of `t` letters and anyway, `wc -l` will print the number of lines in total, so in this case, the total number of `t`s in the file, not the number per line. Try `printf 'foo\tbar' | grep -o '\t' | wc` and then `printf 'foo\tbar' | grep -o $'\t' | wc`.

Comment: @terdon I may have fooled myself. Thanks for pointing out! I'll try.

Answer (score 6):

I think `sed` etc. is not suitable for this, an easy way is to call `awk` with tab as field separator:

```
printf $'hello\tworld\thugo\nfoo\tbar\nbaz\n' | awk -F$'\t' '{print NF-1;}'
```

which gives

```
2
1
0
```

Answer (score 6):

If your goal is only to detect whether there's always the same number of tabs per line (no bash, no awk):

```
sed 's/[^\t]//g' file | sort -u | wc -l
```

If it outputs 1, then it's good!

Or, replacing `sed` with `tr`:

```
tr -cd \\t\\n < file | sort -u | wc -l
```

or if you like useless uses of cats and don't like concatenating options:

```
cat file | tr -c -d \\t\\n | sort -u | wc -l
```

The trick is to remove all non-tab characters on each line, and then sort/uniq what remains.

Comment: Regarding your `tr` solution, why not just `tr -cd "\t" | wc -c`?

Comment: @JosephR. Because `tr -cd \\t` will also remove the newline character, and we want to keep this one!

Comment: OK. Got it. I thought `tr` would respect newline boundaries and produce line-by-line output by default.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the easiest way is to use `awk`:

```
awk -F'\t' '{print NF-1}' foo
```

`NF` is the number of fields, `-F'\t'` tells `awk` to split fields on tabs so the number of tabs will be one less than the number of fields which is why we have `awk` print `NF-1`.

If you really don't want to use `awk` you could do (**note:** this does not count trailing tabs at the end of each line):

```
$ while read line; do echo "$line" | fold -1 | grep -c $'\t'; done < foo
2
4
0
1
0
```

To deal with leading and trailing tabs as well as with other weird characters (such as backslashes), do this instead:

```
$ while IFS= read line; do echo "$line" | fold -1 | grep -c $'\t'; done < foo
```

- `while read lines; do ... ; done < foo` : read each line of file `foo` into the variable `$line`.
- `echo "$line" | fold -1` : the fold command will print one character per line
- `grep -c $'\t'` : this is run on each line of the file (`$line`) but since 
  `$line` has been folded into one character per line, `grep -c` will count the number of tabs in that line. If you don't `fold` first, `grep -c` will count the number of matching lines and will not give you a tab count *per* line.

You could also use Perl of course but I guess that's not available either. Here's one way regardless:

```
perl -lne '@a=/\t/g;print scalar @a' foo
```

Comment: Your non-awk solution doesn't quite work with leading/trailing tabs and consecutive tabs. Use `while IFS= read line` if your shell supports it to fix that.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf yes, I know I pointed that out in my answer (see note). Since the OP specifically asked for non bash scripting, I did not want to use things like `IFS`.

Comment: `IFS` is rather common in shells (not only bash)... so you could mention it in your post `;)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf fair enough, I thought it was a bashism. Any idea if it would be available in the shell the OP's friend is using? If I understand correctly, it is [this one](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) and it claims to be a bash shell so I guess `IFS` would work. By the way, `IFS=` is not needed for consecutive tabs.

Comment: True for consecutive tabs!

Comment: yes, there's bash 3.1. leaving out bash is not a requirement, it's just a 'nice to have'. (Reasoning is, I'm not particularly confident with using bash on windows, but I'm interested in the unix way, and utils are just cute.)

Comment: @naxa most utils work on streams of data, not lines. To work on lines, you tend to need things like awk/sed/perl etc. In this case, the Unix way is awk, by far the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

I ralize its too late, but the OP's command line was almost correct. He just needed the $ in front of his TAB ('\t')

```
grep -o $'\t' infile | wc -l
```

does exaclty what he was after.

Comment: OP's problem was different. Their `grep` didn't support the `-o` option.

Comment: ah, ok. Still very new to this and wondered why if he was so close to an answer everyone too him away from grep.

Comment: That's fine, I suppose. The comments below the question are informative. terdon points out this, and other mistakes in OP's approach (notably, even this does not do what OP wants, which is counting the number of tabs *per line*).